# I want to cast a string of raw data in the form of a matrix to array of integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, casting

i want to cast a string of raw data in the form of a matrix to array of integer in python. But I got stuck and idk what I'm going to do.
this is the raw of data:

```
23  60  79  32  57  74  52  70  82  36
80  77  81  95  41  65  92  85  55  76
52  10  64  75  78  25  80  98  81  67
41  71  83  54  64  72  88  62  74  43
60  78  89  76  84  48  84  90  15  79
34  67  17  82  69  74  63  80  85  61
```

and i want to casting this data to 1d array of integer like this :

```
[21, 60, 79, ...]
```

Comment: Are all the numbers exactly 2 digits?

Comment: I assume the first number of your example should be 23?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
a = data.split(" ")
out = [] # matrix of integers
for i in range(len(a)):
    out.append(int(a[i]))
```

If your data contains newlines, you would need to remove them. Before this code you could do:

```
data = data.replace("\n", " ")
```

Comment: What's `data`? How does this split the line breaks?

Comment: `data` is supposed to be the input data. I assumed that the line breaks were formatting copied here to make it look "better", but I'll edit my answer to remove newlines

Comment: I assume OP is showing a text file, not a raw string

Comment: @OneCricketeer I edited it. There are many online tutorials on how to import a text file into a string. https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-in-python is one such example the OP can use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> data = """
23  60  79  32  57  74  52  70  82  36
80  77  81  95  41  65  92  85  55  76
52  10  64  75  78  25  80  98  81  67
41  71  83  54  64  72  88  62  74  43
60  78  89  76  84  48  84  90  15  79
34  67  17  82  69  74  63  80  85  61
"""
>>> import re
>>> [int(n) for n in re.split(r"[ \n]+", data.strip())]
[23, 60, 79, ..., 61]
```

a brief explanation for this:

1. strip the whitespace around the text
2. split the whole text by one or more whitespaces (including newline)
3. map each items with int